send a value variable in parameter xml using SOAP Request witn php
I'm trying to send SOAP request using PHP injection a variable as parameter in xml ,my variable called $response1 and I'm inject on token part but always i get that the token is empty and I'm sure is not what i missed ?
$requestXML2 = <<<XML
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:agen="http://www.nortel.com/soa/oi/cct/types/AgentService" xmlns:typ="http://www.nortel.com/soa/oi/cct/types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <agen:SetStaticVoiceTerminalRequest>
         <agen:ssoToken>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <typ:token>{$response1}</typ:token>
         </agen:ssoToken>
         <agen:agent>
            <typ:agentLoginId>{$user_agentLoginId}</typ:agentLoginId>
            <typ:userName>?</typ:userName>
            <typ:agentType>?</typ:agentType>
         </agen:agent>
         <agen:terminal>
            <typ:terminalName>{$user_terminalName}</typ:terminalName>
            <typ:terminalType>AGENT</typ:terminalType>
            <typ:provider>
               <typ:providerName>Passive</typ:providerName>
            </typ:provider>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <typ:status>?</typ:status>
         </agen:terminal>
      </agen:SetStaticVoiceTerminalRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
XML;

// SOAP service URL for the second service
$serviceURL2 = "http://10.16.9.10:9080/SOAOICCT/services/AgentService";

// Define SOAP headers for the second service
$headers2 = [
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'SOAPAction: ""'
];

// Initialize the SOAP client for the second service
$client2 = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location' => $serviceURL2,
    'uri' => "http://tempuri.org/",
    'trace' => 1,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => $headers2,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $requestXML2,
        ),
    )),
));

try {
    // Call the SOAP method for the second service
    $response2 = $client2->__doRequest($requestXML2, $serviceURL2, '', SOAP_1_1);

   // echo 'Response2  is : ' . $response2 . "\n\n";
    
    // Print the SOAP response for the second service
  //  echo "Response from second service:\n";
    echo $response2;
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    // Handle SOAP errors
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

I have the token but he can take it from the variable ::

Ignoring SOAP completely, do you see the value(s) when you inspect $requestXML2?

Are you sure the variable is set before you assign to $requestXML2? Is this code in a function? If the variable is set outside the function, you need to pass it as a parameter or use global $response1;

Yes I see the value

The variable gets injected into the string and a new string gets created with that, so the variable is gone (from that perspective). If you believe the value is set correctly, then you can ignore the fact that you are creating a SOAP payload with a variable, and we can diagnose elsewhere. So to be very clear, you have run var_dump($requestXML2);die; immediately after assigning a value to $requestXML2, and the token is in there?

when I run  var_dump($requestXML2);die; I got this :   string(1884) " 8aef342b-4875-4e60-a48d-3ccbb09e7d66 70308579 ? ? Line 236.0.0.3 AGENT Passive ? "

Okay, now view source on that page and you should see the full XML. Copy that and place that and set $requestXML2 to just that (temporarily just for debugging purposes). You should see all of the variables replaced with just text, right? Now try the SOAP call. If it still complains, that proves the variables in the string aren't the problem, and instead you are calling the SOAP method in an unsupported way.

I made a workaround solution using JS to put the response SOAP on hidden input: '';   and it's work fine
